# Mustache Class Mustache_loader_FileSystemLoader not found

Tags: php, class, composer-php, mustache

I'm using Composer to add Mustache in my PHP project.

On the local XAMPP environment all works pretty well. Uploading all on the remote web server raise up the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mustache_loader_FilesystemLoader' not found
```

This is my php script:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$mustache = new Mustache_Engine(array('loader'=> new Mustache_loader_FilesystemLoader('./templates')));
```

Someone said it's a case sensitive issue of the server's file system, but what gotta i do to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're on a case-sensitive filesystem, so you need to use the proper case: `Mustache_Loader_FilesystemLoader` not `Mustache_loader_FilesystemLoader`.

You should *always* use the same case as the actual class name, even when you're not on a case-sensitive filesystem, because at some point you'll want to put it on another server and you'll run into this issue again :)